# Intellij spring boot run cannot find main class... Throws a com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot, program-entry-point

I'm not able to run the spring-boot project using the IDE because it complains about not finding the main class. The main class is entered as a field correctly in the run configuration setup so I'm not sure what would cause this issue.

This is what intellij is running:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Didea.launcher.port=7534 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/learl/Applications/idea-IU-145.597.3/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/learl/Development/SpringBootRestMybatis/target/classes:/home/learl/Downloads/ojdbc7.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.16/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.16/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.16/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/mybatis/spring/boot/mybatis-spring-boot-starter/1.1.1/mybatis-spring-boot-starter-1.1.1.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/mybatis/spring/boot/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.1.1/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.1.1.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/mybatis/mybatis/3.4.0/mybatis-3.4.0.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/mybatis/mybatis-spring/1.3.0/mybatis-spring-1.3.0.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.32/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-juli-8.0.32.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.6/commons-pool-1.6.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc7/1.0.0/ojdbc7-1.0.0.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar:/home/learl/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar:/home/learl/Applications/idea-IU-145.597.3/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain gov.utah.deq.Application
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 

org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 27 more
```

and here is the main class:

```
package gov.utah.deq;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are running the main class directly? Seems you're going to package your app as `war` archive. If so, run the `mvn spring-boot:run` instead. If it ain't work, post the `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`..

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should be able to run it either way with spring-boot, should I not?

Comment: Did you managed to run with `mvn spring-boot:run`? If not, post more details..

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the tomcat starter is in provided scope and [Intellij IDEA does not resolve it properly](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107048). There are various workarounds on the issue.